# How do I use Screenfull.js to make a Google chart fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I am using [screenfull.js](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js/) to allow a Google chart to be viewed in fullscreen.

I want the chart to use 100% of the screen width/height when in full screen mode but be a specific size otherwise (width: 100%; height: 200px). The problem is that my current code results in black bars above and below the chart in fullscreen mode. What am I doing wrong?

My fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bpt22/x2c3zwdu/15/)

HTML:

```
<html>

  <body>

    <input type="button" value="Full Screen Mode" id="button1">
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/screenfull.js/1.0.4/screenfull.min.js"></script>
    <script>


    </script>

    <div id="piechart" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"></div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Javascript (which adapts the Google pie chart [example code](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart)):

```
$(function() {

  $('#button1').click(function() {

    screenfull.request(document.getElementById('piechart'));

  })

})


google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work', 11],
    ['Eat', 2],
    ['Commute', 2],
    ['Watch TV', 2],
    ['Sleep', 7]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'My Daily Activities'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

  chart.draw(data, options);

  $(window).resize(function() {
    chart.draw(data, options);

  });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `style` attribute on the chart's container will need to be changed once in full screen mode,
or else it will still be `height: 200px;`

let's use a css class instead, then we can listen for screenfull's `'change'` event,
and switch the class name, then re-draw the chart, just to be safe

```
  screenfull.on('change', function () {
    if (screenfull.isFullscreen) {
      chartContainer.className = 'chart-full';
    } else {
      chartContainer.className = 'chart-normal';
    }
    drawChart();
  });
```

next, the chart will not fill the container completely by default,
we can use the following config options to maximize the chart

```
chartArea: {
  height: '100%',
  width: '100%',
  top: 48,
  left: 16,
  right: 16,
  bottom: 16
},
height: '100%',
width: '100%'
```

see following snippet...

**js**

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work', 11],
    ['Eat', 2],
    ['Commute', 2],
    ['Watch TV', 2],
    ['Sleep', 7]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'My Daily Activities',
    chartArea: {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      top: 32,
      left: 16,
      right: 16,
      bottom: 16
    },
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%'
  };

  var chartContainer = $('#piechart').get(0);
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(chartContainer);

  $('#button1').click(function() {
    if (screenfull.enabled) {
      screenfull.request(chartContainer);

      screenfull.on('change', function () {
        if (screenfull.isFullscreen) {
          chartContainer.className = 'chart-full';
        } else {
          chartContainer.className = 'chart-normal';
        }
        drawChart();
      });
    }
  })

  drawChart();
  $(window).resize(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
});
```

**css**

```
.chart-normal {
  height: 200px;
}

.chart-full {
  height: 100%;
}
```

**html**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/screenfull.js/3.3.2/screenfull.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Full Screen Mode" id="button1">
<div class="chart-normal" id="piechart"></div>
```

---

working fiddle --> https://jsfiddle.net/0m3x6aea/

Comment: Thank you very much - your suggested solution works perfectly.